# ReactDOM.render(Array, DivContext) only works once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I have built a onClick function to render out a textbox and a label Here:

```
    function buttonAddnewPolygonHandler () {
        var polygonDiv = document.getElementById('polydiv');
        var label = wp.element.createElement("p", null, "Map point Co-Ords" );
        var textbox = wp.element.createElement("input", { type: "text", value: "", onChange: onChangeMapPoint });
        console.log(polygonArrayView);          
        polygonArrayView.push(label,textbox);
        ReactDOM.render(polygonArrayView, polygonDiv);

      }
```

This works great once but when I click the button again the div isn't getting another label and textbox appended to the end of this content

Answer (score 0):

```
    function buttonAddnewPolygonHandler (polygonArrayViews) {

        var polygonDiv = document.getElementById('polydiv');
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(polygonDiv);
        var label = wp.element.createElement("p", null, "Map point Co-Ords" );
        var textbox = wp.element.createElement("input", { type: "text", value: "", onChange: onChangeMapPoint });
        polygonArrayView.push(label, textbox);
        ReactDOM.render(polygonArrayView, polygonDiv);
      }
```

ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(polygonDiv); is needed

Comment: In a simple use case (for a tooltip) [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode) might throw exceptions: *DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.* I have no clue why, yet.